# Raspberry Pi wifi LAN Server how to?

Tags: ssh, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I want to run a Node web server on my Pi, and connect to it via the Pi's wifi. The idea is that I can access the server when I am in the middle of nowhere and just plug the Pi to a 5V output and login the server through my phone. I just want to setup the pi as a LAN network.

Through past research and tests I managed to turn my Pi into an access point but I lost the ability to SSH to it.

At the moment I have a Node server running a webpage and I am able to connect to it as the Pi is connected to a wifi router.

I am wondering if I just need to turn my Pi into an AP or if I need to do some port forwarding too.

My current setup is a RaspberryPi4 with Raspbian and running Node.

Edited -

Added "I just want to setup the pi as a LAN network."

Comment: What do you mean "I am in the middle of nowhere"? If you want to make it to be accessible from Internet and you are behind NAT (which is the common thing) you should add DNAT rule (Port Forwarding) for the port you want to be accessible in your case 80.

Comment: I also did not understand, if you want to make the pi accessible from any network, or walk with the pi in your pocket and connect at any time?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it in my re-write. I want to access the website through LAN and not the internet.

Comment: ok, but like a repeater or a hotspot?

Comment: @Miguel. I believe hotspot, I would have the website running on the PI's. Then I would connect my phone to the Pi's wifi and view the website.

Comment: and you need internet, or just a local network to access the web page?

Comment: @Miguel, The Webpage is running on the Pi, so i would just need the local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the raspberrypi.org documentation has all the information, in the AC I recommend using a wifi adapter, but you can use the pi interface.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

you do not need to configure dhcp, as the site may be located on localhost 127.0.0.1

and recommend to access by phone

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/

if you have any problems in the configuration process put it here

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll read through it.